# Menu items not visible in developer mode odoo V13

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

There are few modules only visible in developer mode.
I need to visible it in non-develope mode. How can i do it?

**My findings:**

I have few xml views in common folder which has xml alone with out  **<**menuitems**>**  and in later point in another folder I have listed all the menuitems from common folder as well as current folder menu items to the order i want.

**why i need to place the menuitems in other folder ?**

If i place the menu items in the common folder, odoo is giving them first as per menu sequences by default.But i need it later. so i combined all the menu items to the order i want in current folder.

It works in Developer mode without any issues. But in non developer mode it isn't.
I have also verified if any groups is making this but no.

I hope i made some sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make visible the invisible menu items in Odoo so for that you've to remove the **`groups`** from the menu items like.

```
<menuitem id="warranty_management_root" parent="stock.menu_stock_config_settings"
                  groups="warranty_management.group_stock_warranty" name="Warranty"/>
```

After removing

```
<menuitem id="warranty_management_root" parent="stock.menu_stock_config_settings"
                   name="Warranty"/>
```

Secondly if there is no group in menu items there is another way to assign groups to menu item like this.

```
<record id="hr.menu_hr_root" model="ir.ui.menu" >
     <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('module_name.group_hr_menu')])]"/>
</record>
```

Just remove this code or comment it will work for you.

Comment: Adam, I dont see any group is associated with menu items in my case. I have the xml in one folder and menu items in another folder.

Answer (score 0):

In menuitem tag, it will be declared with `groups`. If you remove groups in your custom module, it will be visible without turn on developer mode.

NOTE: Understand the purpose of reason to be hide and now visible for all.

Comment: Thanks Bhavesh. But there is no group for any of these menuitems.

Comment: The xml which is located in common folder and its menitems in other folder is creating the issue.

Comment: Can you please share your some code it will help us

Comment: Is this your custom menu / object? If yes, have you created security access rights (read,write, create,delete). If no, can you User profile with that menu object access rights? Make sure logged user has access of data.

Answer (score 0):

you probably forgot to add the model to ir.model.access, here's how:

1. create a security file in: your_module/security/ir.model.access.csv
2. the content of the ir.model.access.csv file should be something like this:

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_model_name_users,access_model_name users,model_**model_name**,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
```

note: replace 'model_name' with your model's name (**replace period with underscore too**)

3. add the ir.model.access.csv file path to manifest:

   'data': [
   'security/ir.model.access.csv',
   ... other files
   ],